# Define mirror repositories in dependency_links of python package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Python's package manager allows defining non-PyPI dependencies via [`dependency_links`](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html) argument of the setup script.  But is it possible to have *mirrors* defined in a similar way as well?  (so, same package, same version, everything the same,- just in two different repositories,- and I want a second one to act as a fallback in case if the first one fails - e.g. host unreachable, authentication failed, etc).

**UPD**

I did already try to define more that one URL for the same package in `dependency_links`.  Unfortunately, this does not work as I would like it to.  In case if the very first repository that is resolved as a correct match for the requested package/version fails for some reason, then the whole setup script just fails (i.e. it does not try to iterate through *all other* correct matches until either a good one is found, or all of them fail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `setuptools`' sources, the default code only does syntax validation of URLs in `dependency_links`, but all the errors occuring on actual file download attempt stop the script execution. In the example below, the default package index impl is overridden, so that besides the URL syntax validation, an attempt to download the target file is being made. If it fails, the process switches to the next URL.

```
from distutils.errors import DistutilsError
import os
import tempfile

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.easy_install import easy_install
from setuptools.package_index import PackageIndex as PackageIndexOrig
import faker


class PackageIndex(PackageIndexOrig):

    def url_ok(self, url, fatal=False):
        if super().url_ok(url, fatal):
            try:
                tmpfile = os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='url-ok-check-'), 'file.out')
                self._attempt_download(url, tmpfile)
                return True
            except Exception as ex:
                msg = 'Download error for %s: %s' % (url, ex)
                if fatal:
                    raise DistutilsError(msg)
                self.warn(msg)
        return False


f = faker.Faker()
fake_urls = [f.url() + '#egg=django' for i in range(10)]
urls = [fake_urls + ['https://github.com/django/django/archive/stable/2.0.x.zip#egg=django']

easy_install.create_index = PackageIndex

setup(
    name='spam',
    packages=['spam'],
    install_requires=['django'],
    dependency_links=urls,
)
```

Test it out:

```
$ pip install faker
$ python setup.py install --verbose
running install
...
Installed /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spam-0.0.0-py3.6.egg
Downloading https://harris.com#egg=django
Download error for https://harris.com#egg=django: Unexpected HTML page found at https://harris.com#egg=django
Downloading https://www.torres.com#egg=django
Download error for https://www.torres.com#egg=django: Download error for https://www.torres.com#egg=django: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:777)
Downloading https://smith.com/#egg=django
Download error for https://smith.com/#egg=django: Download error for https://smith.com/#egg=django: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)
Downloading http://tucker.info/#egg=django
Download error for http://tucker.info/#egg=django: Unexpected HTML page found at http://tucker.info/#egg=django
Downloading https://christian-murphy.org/#egg=django
Download error for https://christian-murphy.org/#egg=django: Download error for https://christian-murphy.org/#egg=django: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Downloading http://www.ramirez.com/#egg=django
Download error for http://www.ramirez.com/#egg=django: Unexpected HTML page found at http://www.ramirez.com/#egg=django
Downloading http://www.perez-davis.com/#egg=django
Download error for http://www.perez-davis.com/#egg=django: Download error for http://www.perez-davis.com/#egg=django: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Downloading https://ramirez.org/#egg=django
Download error for https://ramirez.org/#egg=django: Download error for https://ramirez.org/#egg=django: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Downloading https://www.bridges.com/#egg=django
Download error for https://www.bridges.com/#egg=django: Download error for https://www.bridges.com/#egg=django: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Downloading https://bryant.org/#egg=django
Download error for https://bryant.org/#egg=django: Download error for https://bryant.org/#egg=django: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Downloading http://porter-griffith.com/#egg=django
Download error for http://porter-griffith.com/#egg=django: Download error for http://porter-griffith.com/#egg=django: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Downloading https://www.hooper.net/#egg=django
Download error for https://www.hooper.net/#egg=django: Download error for https://www.hooper.net/#egg=django: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Downloading https://github.com/django/django/archive/stable/2.0.x.zip#egg=django
Processing dependencies for spam==0.0.0
Searching for django
Best match: django [unknown version]
Downloading https://github.com/django/django/archive/stable/2.0.x.zip#egg=django
Downloading https://github.com/django/django/archive/stable/2.0.x.zip#egg=django
Processing 2.0.x.zip
...
```

---

The drawback of the overridden `PackageIndex` is that once a valid link is found, the script downloads the distribution twice - first when validating the link, then when actually downloading it for installation. This can be avoided by writing a more fine-grained check than just using the `_attempt_download()` method. Or you can store the reference to the downloaded file and then reuse it in the `_download_url()` method:

```
class PackageIndex(PackageIndexOrig):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._attempted = None

    def url_ok(self, url, fatal=False):
        if super().url_ok(url, fatal):
            try:
                tmpfile = os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='url-ok-check-'), 'file.out')
                self._attempted = self._attempt_download(url, tmpfile)
                return True
            except Exception as ex:
                msg = 'Download error for %s: %s' % (url, ex)
                if fatal:
                    raise DistutilsError(msg)
                self.warn(msg)
        return False

    def _download_url(self, scheme, url, tmpdir):
        if self._attempted is not None:
            (result, self._attempted) = (self._attempted, None)
            return result
        return super()._download_url(scheme, url, tmpdir)
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with appending `'#egg=django'`. It is still a valid URL. But you're right, the URL validation in `url_ok` method is just doing basic stuff like checks for URL syntax and does not actually try to download the file. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I think it can not get any closer to what I am looking for (short of getting your implementation of `url_ok` into the official `setuptools`.